# mysql can't create table named ‘user’

Tags: mysql

[image]

but  I used NetBeans,then I can create table user.

[image]

Comment: use and user are [keywords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html). Do not use this as a table or column Name.

Comment: Thanks, I will pay attention. But I don't konw why I can create table named 'user' with NetBeans

Comment: Because netbeans also use mysql Statements or what do you mean?

Comment: At first, thanks erery one. And I found the problem. I drop the database named 'mysql', and create a new database named 'mysql'. It' can't create table named 'user'. But I create another database named 'myworld', then I can create it. NetBeans also use mysql.Thank you.

Comment: if you drop the mysql database you get very big problems

Comment: Aaaaa....I thought it was an example for novice. Should I reInstall the mysql     to restore it？

Comment: i think you have no other Chance. In this table are the base Information stored, like user and previliges

Comment: Did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

User is a Keyword. If you want to use as Tablename you must put it in backticks like.

```
CREATE TABLE `user` ( ....
```

**sample**

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `user` (
    ->   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `userName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `password` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `realName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,02 sec)

mysql> insert into `user` (id) VALUE (99);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> select * from `user`;
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| id | userName | password | realName |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| 99 | NULL     | NULL     | NULL     |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: i have add a sample in my answer

Comment: At first, thanks erery one. And I found the problem. I drop the database named 'mysql', and create a new database named 'mysql'. It' can't create table named 'user'. But I create another database named 'myworld', then I can create it. 
And  use the statement in database 'mysql'

Comment: CREATE TABLE 'user' (
    'id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   'userName' varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    'password` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    `realName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''id' int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 'userName' varchar(32) DEFAULT N' at line 2

Comment: CREATE TABLE user (
    id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    userName varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    password varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    realName varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

and it's ok in database 'myworld'
create table user(
    id Integer auto_increment,
    userName varchar(32) unique not null,
    password varchar(32) not null,
    realName varchar(32),
    primary key (id)
);